# Kendo TreeList: expanded should stay expanded for user experience

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-treelist

I have a Kendo TreeList and can edit each item. After editing, I do

```
treeList.dataSource.read();
```

This causes every item to collapse (because the default .expand is false).

But I want that everything (items expanded by the user, items not expanded) stays the same, just the edited item/row should change in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my issue :

https://www.telerik.com/forums/restoring-treelist-expanded-state-after-refresh

I had to save the expanded state and restore it every time I call `treeList.dataSource.read()`.

Therefore,  I used an `onDataBinding` method to save and an `onDataBound` method to restore.